# Rails - find_by_sql + Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to get objects from my MySQL database using a stored procedure I have created.

```
@locs = Location.find_by_sql("CALL geodist(100.4058, 37.7907, 10000, 'Sample')")
```

This results in the following error

```
Location Load (6.4ms)  CALL geodist(100.4058, 37.7907, 10000, 'Sample')
Completed   in 37ms

Mysql2::Error (Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now):
```

The following however works fine:

```
@locations = Location.connection.select_all("CALL geodist(100.4058, 37.7907, 10000, 'Sample')")
```

However, it doesn't return objects, only a hash of values.

Is there any way to get find_by_sql to work? If not, how can I manually instantiate AR models without querying the database again?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find out what is goin on ?

Answer (score 1):

you can build objects yourself by sending every hash to constructor of your active record model

```
@locations = Location.connection.select_all("CALL geodist(100.4058, 37.7907, 10000, 'Sample')")
results = Array.new
@locations.each do |location|
  results[] = Location.new(location)
end
```

UPD:
by the way it's strange behaviour I just looked at find_by_sql method realization it looks familiar
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql